# getaddrinfo: No addre ss associated with hostname (SocketError)

Tags: ruby, git, ssh

I need help. I have trouble when I try to push sources to exist repository on my gitlab hosting. When I do

```
ssh -vT git@git.host.org
```

or

```
git push -u origin master #in repository folder
```

I see

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `initialize': getaddrinfo: No addre
ss associated with hostname (SocketError)
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `open'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `block in connect'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:52:in `timeout'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:877:in `connect'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:862:in `do_start'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:851:in `start'
        from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_net.rb:62:in `get'
        from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_net.rb:24:in `discover'
        from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_shell.rb:77:in `user'
        from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_shell.rb:82:in `username'
        from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_shell.rb:36:in `exec'
```

How can I solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Site `host.org` doesn't work properly.

Comment: Site name was replaced

Comment: Anyway, something wrong with: 1) site you are goint to 2) DNS error or absent 3) your network doesnt work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're using gitlab/gitlabhq and getting this error. But I got this error when using gitlab. In my config.yml in /home/git/gitlab-shell/config.yml i had typed my gitlab_url wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Jerinaw answer, these might be the reasons-

1. Check if remotes are correct using remote -v
2. Check your host credentials
3. Check ssh key

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Network access to git.host.org is given:

> getaddrinfo: No addre
>   ss associated with hostname (SocketError)

means that to your DNS Name git.host.org there is no corresponding address which can be resolved.

you can try nslookup your host:

```
$nslookup git.host.org
```

it should give you a adress corresponding to that host otherwise your server doesnt know where to connect. But you will probably not. If you want to fix that only for your server you can put in **/etc/hosts** something like

```
192.168.1.100 git.host.org
```

where 192.168.1.100 must be the correct address to your remote server. 
Or you can use the ip address in the first place.